# TIME complexity of this criss-cross looped program. this is to print N prime numbers

Tags: c++, time-complexity, primes

I want to know how to calculate the TIME complexity for this program, the 10 in outer loop defines the number of primes to print. You can suppose it as N. for now this prints 10 prime numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int number=2;
    bool flg=0;
    cout<<2<<"\t";
    number=3;
    for(int count=1;count<10;number+=2){
        for(int j = 3;j<(number/2);j+=2){
            if(number%j==0){
                flg=1;
                break;
            }    
        }
        if(flg==0)
            {cout<<number<<"\t";count++;}
        else
            flg=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time complexity is a concept of how the calculations increase over time,  i.e. O(N) means that the number of computations linearly depend on the number of items you want to compute. So this question seems offtopic for Stack Overflow, because it's about mathematics and not about coding.

Comment: Well, it's going to be the product of the outer loop iterations and the inner loop iterations. The outer loop iterations is easy, it's just N/2. The inner loop is much trickier, probably involving log(N) factors because of the prime number theorem.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk You got the inner and outer loop mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming integer operations are counted as constant time and ignoring limited range of actual C++ integers:

Because of the prime number theorem, the outer loop will be iterated `Theta(N ln(N))` times.

Asymptotically almost all of these iterations are for non-primes because the density of non-primes in the (odd) natural numbers is converging to one.

The inner loop for a non-prime `m` takes `Theta(m)` time.

Therefore, in total, the time complexity of the algorithm is `Theta(N^2 ln(N))`.

Comment: The outer loop goes from 1 to N by twos. I'd call that N/2.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk No, the outer loop goes while `count<N`, but in each iteration `number` is increased by two, not `count`. (see `for(int count=1;count<10;number+=2)` which is certainly confusingly written) `count` is increased only when a prime is found in `{cout<<number<<"\t";count++;}`.

Comment: Ahh, that's very confusing. Thanks.